# Making a Javascript Loop request in rails view

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, coffeescript

I need to download a file from a link I am given. In order to do this I must make a get request to that link. It can have 3 states:
1. Code 200 and the download will begin once the request landed
2. Code 202 which means I must repeat the request because the file is being uploaded
3. Error code and I must create a dom element that shows that.

How it works:
I make a request to this rails action:

```
def by_month
    export_form = Commissions::ByMonthForm.new(current_user)
    if export_form.submit(params)
      @export = export_form.export
    else
      show_errors export_form.errors
    end
  end
```

This in turn starts the file upload. Which I don't know when it's ready(depending on how big the file it is). Now I must create a javascript get request to a link that follows the indications I have given at the beginning of the post. And integrate it in the by_month.html.erb view from rails . The javascript I managed to write is:

```
function httpGetAsync(theUrl){
      var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(xmlHttp.readyState == 4) {
          if (xmlHttp.status == 200) {
            redirect_to_main();
          }
          else if(xmlHttp.status == 202) {
            httpGetAsync(theUrl);   
          }
          else {
            make_error_css();
          }
        }
      }
      xmlHttp.open("GET", theUrl, true); // true for asynchronous
      xmlHttp.send(null);
    }
```

However I don't think it works. Any ideas of how I can do this?(redirect_to_main and make_error_css are functions that I will implement myself later).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update** As per the comments below

Can you try this,

```
function httpGetAsync(theUrl){
      var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(xmlHttp.readyState == 4) {
          if (xmlHttp.status == 200) {
            redirect_to_main();
          }
          else if(xmlHttp.status == 202) {
           setTimeout(
            makeRequest(theUrl),
             3000);   
          }
          else {
            make_error_css();
          }
        }
      }
      //makeRequest(xmlHttp, theUrl);
      xmlHttp.open("GET", theUrl, true); // true for asynchronous
      xmlHttp.send(null);

    }

function makeRequest(theUrl){
           httpGetAsync(theUrl);
        }
```

`makeRequest()` is where the request is made again if the status is 202.

Comment: but if the status is again 202 I need to remake it(there can be an undefinite number of 202 answers since I am waiting for a document download, I need to repeat this call every 3 seconds or something

Comment: So from what i understand is, if the status is 202 (doesn't matter how many times), each time you got to wait for 3 seconds and make a fresh call again? Is my understanding correct?

Comment: function makeRequest(theUrl) {
  setTimeout(httpGetAsync(theUrl), 3000);
}; something like this :D

Comment: hi @LucianTarna I have made some changes, see if this answers your concerns :)